# Python getting first item from requests reponse

Tags: python

I am querying an API using python requests like this...

```
url = "www.example.com"
response = requests.request("POST", url)

response
--------
[
  {
    "id": "485744",
    "descript": "firstitem",
  },
  {
    "id": "635456",
    "descript": "seconditem",
  },
  {
    "id": "765554",
    "descript": "thirditem",
  },
]
```

I am trying to access the first item in the response like this...

```
response = response.json
print(response[0])
```

But I am getting the error...

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It should be `response.json()`

Comment: If  you print `type(response)`, u will get to know why it is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json` is a method of the `Response` class and not an attribute of the object. To get the json data, use:

```
response = response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't properly called it: `response.json()`

Alternate method:

```
import json #import this on the top
response = json.loads(response) #You need to load the data into JSON
```

**ALSO**: The additional commas (,) at the end of each `"descript"`:

`"firstitem"`, `"seconditem"`, `"thirditem"` is not required and may give errors.